# How to use R to batch rename many files based on sequential parent folder names

Tags: r, loops, file, batch-rename

I have 1 TB of video and associated files for my MSc project, and I am trying to rename all the files in R. The parent folder-subfolder layout for **each** video camera is as such:

- Camera ID (e.g., C00125)

  - YYYY_MM

    - DD

      - HH (in 24-hour format)

        - CameraID_HHMMSS_#15 (File name)
    - DD
    - DD
    - DD
  - YYYY_MM

Within each of the final subfolders, there are a variable number of files, and each unique file name has 3 different file types associated with it: an AVI File, LBC File, and Wav File. So, if a final subfolder only had 1 video (there can be up to 6 videos), there would still be 3 files, e.g. C00141_192000_#15, C00141_192000_#15.lbc, and C00141_192000_#15. The LBC Files have a file extension ".lbc" at the end of each file name.

I need to compile all the files from each **camera** into 1 folder per camera, but frustratingly I would then have a bunch of files with the same file name based on HHMMSS, and the file name would not indicate what YYYYMMDD each file is actually associated with. As such, I need to rename each **file** so that it has the corresponding YYYYMMDD added to the current filename which already has the CameraID and HHMMSS. The best way I can see to do this would be to take the YYYYMMDD information from the previous **three** parent folders of each file (unless you could somehow skip the HH subfolder). I don't care whether or not I keep the "_#15".

Ideally this would result in the file name **C00141_2021_05_09_192000_#15** (for each of the three file types from the above example).
But given the nature of the subfolders, I would be fine with something like **2021_05_09_19_C00141_192000_#15**. All that really matters is that the file name is unique to its corresponding CameraID, YYYYMMDD, and HHMMSS, **and** that the files can be sorted chronologically in file explorer once they have been renamed and pooled together.

I have looked into multiple other forums, but the answers are too specialized to the particular file names in the post and don't address multiple subfolders. I have also looked into the "Bulk Rename Utility" Web app, which does roughly what I need, but only 1 subfolder at time, which is not practical for the amount of subfolders I have (15 cameras x 3 months x ~30 days x 24 hours)

I have been struggling with this for 2 full days, and I haven't been able to make much progress. I can't make any progress on my project until I figure this out, so I would really appreciate any help! I am relatively new to R and programming.

Comment: It seems not very difficult, but I fail to understand what's your specific desired result. Can you  give a minimal example, including the original directory structure and your final desired directory structure?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd do it. This assumes your working directory is the folder with all the "Camera ID (e.g., C00125)" folders. Also, I HIGHLY recommend that you make a backup of your data before you do this. I'm using `file.copy()` here to be safe. `file.rename()` is probably faster...

You could easily use regex to rename the files to whatever you want based on their file path. If you are picky about this, let me know, but based on your question, this isn't a huge deal. I'm suggesting using the simplest way of making sure the videos names retain as much info as possible.

**There is no guarantee that this will work. Experiment with a subset of your data first. Back up your data before attempting this!**

```
# Create new folder to move all video files into
new_dir <- "./new_dir"
dir.create(new_dir)

# Get all target files
old_names <- list.files(recursive=TRUE)
old_names
#> [1] C00125/YYYY_MM/DD/HH/CameraID_HHMMSS_#15.avi

# Rename files by reordering elements and replacing slashes
# with underscores
new_names <- gsub(
  pattern = "^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$",
  replacement = "\\2_\\3_\\4_\\1_\\5",
  x = old_names)
new_names
#> [1] "YYYY_MM_DD_HH_C00125_CameraID_HHMMSS_#15.avi"

file.copy(from=old_names, to=paste0(new_dir, "/", new_names))
#> [1] TRUE

Created on 2021-12-11 by the reprex package (v2.0.1)
```

Comment: thank you very much! It worked with my sample subset. I ended up changing it to  pattern = "^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$",
  replacement = "\\1_\\2_\\3_\\5",     because I don't need the standalone 'HH' in the file name. If it is easy enough, I would appreciate knowing how to remove the second 'CameraID' out of the new name format "CameraID_YYYY_MM_DD_CameraID_HHMMSS_#15.avi" just to make it easier to read. Would appreciate it if you'd be willing to show me.

Comment: Sure! You can use more pattern matching with gsub. For example, `gsub(pattern = "_CameraID_", replacement = "", x = "CameraID_YYYY_MM_DD_CameraID_HHMMSS_#15.avi")`. I highly recommend learning regex... it's very useful and for some people, fun! https://regexcrossword.com/

Comment: Or, all together: `gsub(pattern = "^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/CameraID_(.*)$", replacement = "CameraID_\\1_\\2_\\3_\\5", x = old_names)`

Comment: awesome, thanks! So, I would have to do it for each camera folder individually because they all have a unique camera ID? Or is there a way to use gsub to match the pattern of the camera names (since they all start C00, followed by 3 numerical digits and an underscore) so that each file name starts with the unique camera ID? e.g., be able to turn C00140/2021_05/19/20/C00140_204000_#15.avi    into    C00140_2021_05_19_204000_#15.avi   for any camera ID all with one set of code?

Comment: From looking at regex characters, could it be something where it deletes anything that looks like "C00....$" so that all that would be remaining in the '5' position is the HHMMSS? I tried something like this but I couldn't get it to work

Comment: You could try `gsub(pattern = "^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/C00\\d{3}_(.*)$", replacement = "\\1_\\2_\\3_\\5", x = old_names)`. In regex, digits are `\\d` and can be suffixed by a number in curly brackets to indicate how many digits `{3}`.

Comment: Hi @LGH14, were you able to figure this out?

Comment: yes I was, many thanks for your help!